# copying openXML image from one document to another

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk, mailmerge

We have conditional Footers that `INCLUDETEXT` based on the client:

`IF $CLIENT = "CLIENT1" "{INCLUDETEXT "CLIENT1HEADER.DOCX"}" ""`

Depending on our document, there could be a varying amount of `IF/ELSE`, and these all work correctly for merging the correct files in the correct place.

However, some of these documents may have client specific images/branding, which also need to be copied across from the `INCLUDETEXT` file.

Below is the method that is called to replace any `Picture` elements that exist in the `IEnumerable<Run>` that is copied from the Source document to the Target document.

The image is copied fine, however it doesn't appear to update the RID in my `Picture` or add a record into the .XML.Rels files. (I even tried adding a `ForEach` to add to all the headers and footers, to see if this made any difference.

```
    private void InsertImagesFromOldDocToNewDoc(WordprocessingDocument source, WordprocessingDocument target, IEnumerable<Picture> pics)
    {
        IEnumerable<Picture> imageElements = source.MainDocumentPart.Document.Descendants<Run>().Where(x => x.Descendants<Picture>().FirstOrDefault() != null).Select(x => x.Descendants<Picture>().FirstOrDefault());

        foreach (Picture pic in pics) //the new pics
        {
            Picture oldPic = imageElements.Where(x => x.Equals(pic)).FirstOrDefault();

            if (oldPic != null)
            {
                string imageId = "";

                ImageData shape = oldPic.Descendants<ImageData>().FirstOrDefault();

                ImagePart p = source.MainDocumentPart.GetPartById(shape.RelationshipId) as ImagePart;

                ImagePart newPart = target.MainDocumentPart.AddPart<ImagePart>(p);

                newPart.FeedData(p.GetStream());

                shape.RelId = target.MainDocumentPart.GetIdOfPart(newPart);
                string relPart = target.MainDocumentPart.CreateRelationshipToPart(newPart);
            }
        }
    }
```

Has anyone come across this issue before?

It appears the OpenXML SDK documentation is a 'little' sparse...

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 10):

Late reaction but this thread helped me a lot to got it working. Here my solution for copying a document with images

```
private static void CopyDocumentWithImages(string path)
{
    if (!Path.GetFileName(path).StartsWith("~$"))
    {
        using (var source = WordprocessingDocument.Open(path, false))
        {
            using (var newDoc = source.CreateNew(path.Replace(".docx", "-images.docx")))
            {
                foreach (var e in source.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Elements())
                {
                    var clonedElement = e.CloneNode(true);
                    clonedElement.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Blip>()
                        .ToList().ForEach(blip =>
                        {
                            var newRelation = newDoc.CopyImage(blip.Embed, source);
                            blip.Embed = newRelation;
                        });
                    clonedElement.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Vml.ImageData>().ToList().ForEach(imageData =>
                    {
                        var newRelation = newDoc.CopyImage(imageData.RelationshipId, source);
                        imageData.RelationshipId = newRelation;
                    });
                    newDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.AppendChild(clonedElement);
                }
                newDoc.Save();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

CopyImage:

```
public static string CopyImage(this WordprocessingDocument newDoc, string relId, WordprocessingDocument org)
{
    var p = org.MainDocumentPart.GetPartById(relId) as ImagePart;
    var newPart = newDoc.MainDocumentPart.AddPart(p);
    newPart.FeedData(p.GetStream());
    return newDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetIdOfPart(newPart);
}
```

CreateNew:

```
public static WordprocessingDocument CreateNew(this WordprocessingDocument org, string name)
{
    var doc = WordprocessingDocument.Create(name, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);
    doc.AddMainDocumentPart();
    doc.MainDocumentPart.Document = new Document(new Body());
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(org.MainDocumentPart.ThemePart.GetStream()))
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(doc.MainDocumentPart.AddNewPart<ThemePart>().GetStream(FileMode.Create)))
    {
        streamWriter.Write(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
    }
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(org.MainDocumentPart.StyleDefinitionsPart.GetStream()))
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(doc.MainDocumentPart.AddNewPart<StyleDefinitionsPart>().GetStream(FileMode.Create)))
    {
        streamWriter.Write(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
    }
    return doc;
}
```

Comment: I'll dig out the original source and see ;) Thanks

Comment: This worked for me, thanks a lot. I wish there was a way to clone an image from an OpenXmlElement without the need to refer to the parent document.

Comment: Perfect! save me a lot of effort!

Comment: @Marcel Hoekstra Is this the only problem when you copy fragment of word-document into another word-document? Themes, sreadsheets, styles... they must be copied the same complex way in order to be correctly viewed in the result document?

Comment: After copying image that way I get an error from Word:


Word found unreadable content in "document.docx". Do you want to recover the contents of this document? If you trust the source of the document, click yes.

Answer (score 1):

Stuart,

I had faced the same problem when I was trying to copy the numbering styles from one document to the other.

I think what Word does internally is, whenever an object is copied from one document to the other the ID for that object is not copied over to the new document and instead what happens is a new ID is assigned to it.

You'll have to get the ID after the image has been copied and then replace it everywhere your image has been used.

I hope this helps, this is what I to use copy numbering styles.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks, but that's what I'm already doing - using FeedData(Stream) and then getting the part ID afterwards.